# Add canonical id using aws cli or ansible to s3 bucket acl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible, aws-cli

I am implementing a change for vendor wherein I need to add vendor aws account canonical id to my s3 bucket ACL which I did from aws console manually, however, I need to automate this change using either aws CLI or ansible. I explored this and didn't get any possible automation option. Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved?

[image]

Please find attached image above for your reference.

Comment: what about [put-bucket-acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to use [put-object-acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html) or [put-bucket-acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html) on s3api. You need to have acl template on your side and prepare end-version by some sort of script with params.